# Images in Smaller Browser

Tags: html, image, css

http://graduateland.com/

How do i prevent the images from compression. When I reduce the size of my browser window, the image get compressed side way, it's like the human head being compressed.

Looking at that website as an example, the image size isnt affected when screen size changes, only the position of the image changes. How do i do that?

Current CSS

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
min-width: 100%;
height: 500px;
```

Comment: Inspect element is your friend

Comment: Note: be careful with the term "compression". In the web world it usually means "shrinking the size (in bytes) of an item without losing too much of its quality, if possible".

Answer (score 1):

If you want images to be resized when the window shrinks, just change `height: 500px` to `height: auto` in the CSS you posted.  This will force images to keep their original ratio as the `width` changes.  The way your code works right now is that it resizes the image horizontally so it is never wider than its container, but has a fixed height, which messes up the aspect ratio once it begins to shrink horizontally.

If you want the image to stay the same size and just move position as the browser window shrinks you need to apply them as a `background-image`.  Try this CSS code on the container div you want to apply the image background to:

```
#container {
    background: url(path/to/image.jpg) no-repeat center top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@media`, like:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) and (max-height: 1024px) {
    .splash {
        background-image: url('../img/splash-1280.jpg');
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1281px) and (max-width: 1920px) and (max-height: 960px) {
    .splash {
        background-image: url('../img/splash-1920.jpg');
    }
}
```

---

In their CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 1280px)
    [id="get-started"] {
    background-size: auto;
    background-position: center top;
}
```

Which overrides:

```
background-position: center center;
background-size: 100%;
```

Comment: Thanks i will consider this but hmm i'm still trying to wonder how other website does it, it's like the images doesn't change at all just that the view of the image is lesser

Comment: Yea, look in their CSS.

Comment: The only difference i see is i have a img tag, they dont. does that affect?

Comment: They're using background-size to stretch, so yea.

Answer (score 0):

On the site you linked they are appyling this CSS

```
display: table;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin-top: 0;
padding-bottom: 0;
background-image: url("a/image.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-size: 100%;
```

onto a div. But there are great inspector tools which can inspect that for you, so don't ask if you have a 'living' example.

You should particularly have a look at the background properties.

Comment: I think the crux of it is the background-size:100%

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer:
[Responsive Images with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736363/responsive-images-with-css)

CSS:

```
max-width:100% !important;
height:auto;
display:block;
```

Comment: Tried this, hmm i dont really want the image to move :\ Thanks XD