# style css doesent affect the images i put using .php

Tags: php, css

i was puting some company logos in my landing web site which i wantes to use as buttons for the next pages to go in...but first everything was ok. i inserted them through .php and than positioned them in css, and than i tried to make some hover animation and it destroyed it all. than i deleted all the ":hover" codes and everything i added to do that, but now its not as it was. i cant move my pictures to the desired positions. below ill post my .php code and .css as well. please help!!!

```
<div class="maroonlogo">
    <a href="http://maroon.maroon27.com" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://maroon27.com/wp-content/themes/onesie/images/weblogo.png"/>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="line">
    <img src="http://maroon27.com/wp-content/themes/onesie/images/line.png"/>
</div>

<div class="27logo">
    <a href="http://27.maroon27.com" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://maroon27.com/wp-content/themes/onesie/images/logo.png"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
maroonlogo { 
    display: inline; 
    float:right; 
    position:absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 350px;
} 

.line {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 180px;
    left: 600px;
} 

.27logo { 
    display: inline;
    float: right; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 200px; 
    left: 500px; 
}
```

Comment: .maroonlogo
{
display: inline;
float:right;
position:absolute;
top: 200px;
left: 350px;
}

.line
{
display: inline;
float: right;
position: absolute;
top: 180px;
left: 600px;
}

.27logo
{
display: inline;
float: right;
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
left: 500px;
}

Comment: What are the "desired positions"?

Comment: sorry in the comment is my css. for some reason i couldnt post it in my question. it says wrong coding...smthng. im new in ur forum and coding as well.

Comment: i chnaged the positions in the css but the .27logo is not moving even a pixel

Comment: The browser can't tell and doesn't care how the HTML and CSS was created. So PHP is irrelevant, all that matters is what the browser receives.

Comment: Welcome to SO! As a first start, try reading the help page entitled [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). That will help you anticipate some of the questions that users will be asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose if you can't able to change the classname, still we have solution to apply the style for the class "27logo". You need to use special character "\3" for each number like below.

```
.\32\37logo
{
 background-color:#ff00ff;
 height:200px;
 width:200px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vM3Nh/)

Comment: nice Suresh, looks like a good trick. :) even though johny dew's solution worked and i was able to change the class name, i'll keep this in mind :) thnx again guys. ur so helpfull...

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai It is possible, but do you think that it is a good practice? Since language don't usually permit the use of an integer as first character for the definition of a variable and that you have to use a work around to get the result you want.

Comment: It is just an idea in some cases he can't able to modify the class name.

Answer (score 1):

CSS classes cannot start with an integer i.e.: `27logo`

Also, there is no need to put a float if you are using `position:absolute` as it will be meaning less.

Comment: ohhh yesss :D u mean the problem was the "27" number, right? i thought about this earlier but than i totally forgot to change it. thnxxx alot!!!

Comment: hi people. thanx for helping me last night. now i need another thing. maybe this might be a little bit more complicated for me but i need to do it. so, how do i make these image responsive ?

Comment: The post is talking about it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736363/responsive-images-with-css