# Viewport is not working anymore

Tags: html, responsive-design, web, viewport

I made a very simple site www.abasi.info/viewport

Consists out of:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<p><img alt="18" src="18.gif" style="height:55px; width:550px;"></p>



</body>
</html>
```

The numbers should go until 18. But with my Android Phone (Version 2.3.6) the viewport doesn't adjust. It is zoomed in to much. I just had this one picture in the site (nothing else). And if the above viewport would work it would show all the numbers in the pictures until 18. It is very strange.

Comment: have you added @media all (){} in css styleheet

Comment: To make it responsive you want to add `max-width: 100%;`..

Comment: @Vitorino This above code is everything that I added and should make the site to the device with and not cut it off, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Responsive Images with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736363/responsive-images-with-css)

Comment: @Doctus I don't want that the picture adjust to the screen. It is about another site that should not be smaller than 550px and I am trying to have the whole site to be the same size like the device.

Comment: Then add `min-width: 550px` and `max-width: 100%`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the Image 100% width and auto height, so the ratio won't mess up.

example -

```
img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1n9jnaxw/

you also can use max-width, but make sure you define the image dimensions first.

To limit the viewport to 550px you will have to change it to-

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=550, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: But I want that the viewport adjust to the width of the site. The sites width is 550px, so I want the site to be 550px width.

Comment: Regarding latest edit: Sorry, I don't want at the end a fixed viewport. I want a fluent one. I submitted the example to demonstrate that width=device-width is not working.

Comment: try to use <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale:1.0">

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work. There is something wrong with the initial scale. When I double tap on the screen the site adjusts to the device.

Comment: have you deleted "initial scale" ?