# Part of Image Covered in Responsive View

Tags: html, css

I have an image animation that's created using a CSS mask, but for some reason, my media query's `max-width: 100%;` property on `img` is hiding/covering part of the image. If I remove it, it displays normally, but then the images aren't responsive.

Code/demo can be found here (resize Result window to reproduce): http://jsfiddle.net/x2hnomhs/.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Refer this question http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736363/responsive-images-with-css&ei=qIm0jrM_&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=25&ts=1437755085&sig=AKQ9UO-alhUaPGlkI2MeoJABlUAgjMZaKg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `height:auto` to `height:100%` in you `@media screen and (max-width: 940px)`

snippet:

```css
.logo {
  display: block;
  width: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.logo a {
  display: block;
  height: 288px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 450px;
  position: relative;
}
.logo a img.logoMask {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.logo a img.color {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 3px;
  -webkit-animation: logoColor 15s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: logoColor 15s infinite;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes logoColor {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  50% {
    left: -2500px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}
/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes logoColor {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  50% {
    left: -2500px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 940px) {
  img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <a style="padding-right: 0">
    <img src="http://api.marioparra.me/img/api-logo-mask.png" class="logoMask" />
    <img src="http://api.marioparra.me/img/api-logo-gradient.png" class="color" />
  </a>

</div>
```

**UPDATE**: Based on OP comments (*clarifying what OP really wants to achieve*)

Since you want to make the same kind of `animation`in all the viewport sizes and make it responsive  here is a snippet (*comments were added to explain changes*):

```css
.logo {
  display: block;
  max-width: 450px;
  /* changed from width to max-width */
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* added this */
}
.logo a {
  display: block;
  height: 288px;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 450px;
  /* changed from width to max-width */
  position: relative;
}
.logo a img.logoMask {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.logo a img.color {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: -50%;
  /* changed from 3px to -50% */
  -webkit-animation: logoColor 5s infinite;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: logoColor 5s infinite;
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

@-webkit-keyframes logoColor {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  50% {
    left: -2500px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}
/* Standard syntax */

@keyframes logoColor {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  50% {
    left: -2500px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}
/*removed uncessary media queries because you are using now max-width in your parent container , with that your img {width:100%} it is enough to make it responsive. */

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .logo a img.color {
    top: -60%
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  .logo a img.color {
    top: -72%
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <a style="padding-right: 0">
    <img src="http://api.marioparra.me/img/api-logo-mask.png" class="logoMask" />
    <img src="http://api.marioparra.me/img/api-logo-gradient.png" class="color" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this and it causes the image to be completely hidden/covered--it needs to be visible as the animation scrolls sideways.

Comment: Hmm I didn't when I ran your code and resized the window

Comment: Ok I see you don't want to get blank between images (animation start/finish), I thought you want 2 kind of `animations´  for different viewports. If you want, I can update my answer and tell you the fix

Comment: Yeah, I thought it might've been a little confusing. If you can help, that'd be great

Comment: This is better, but I still need a media query with `max-width: 100%;` for `img` since there are other images throughout the website that contains this. I also noticed that in your code, the image gets cut off a little at the bottom (in desktop and mobile)

Comment: for images that is cutting of, just play with the `top:-50%`, if you want to use images with `max-width:100%` across site then just set this ones `max-width:none`

Comment: That did it, and I'm so close, but now there's an issue with the height in mobile and I'm not sure how to fix it without setting static values: http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//api.marioparra.me&w=375&h=667&a=37&s=1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84215/discussion-between-dippas-and-mario-parra).

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured it out. Hope this is what you are looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/x2hnomhs/2/

```
.logo {
    display: block;
    max-width: 450px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.logo a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;    
}

.logo a img.logoMask {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
}

.logo a img.color {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 3px;
    -webkit-animation: logoColor 15s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: logoColor 15s infinite;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes logoColor {
    0%   {left: 0;}
    50%  {left: -2500px;}
    100% {left: 0;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes logoColor {
    0%   {left: 0;}
    50%  {left: -2500px;}
    100% {left: 0;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This did it! What did you change? Just so I can understand the solution

Comment: Nevermind--the issue is still there with the media query, which I need for other images: http://jsfiddle.net/x2hnomhs/3/