# How do I make my images responsive?

Tags: css, image, mobile, responsive

[image]
I can't make my featured images responsive despite internet advice about max-width:100% or auto.

My site is vladmakeev.net

Tablets and phones are shown cropped image. I want full image, what to do?

I made changes that I saw in answer, and my image became proper sized, but it is center on the outside and I can't place in in the middle.
[After changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVBAU.png)

[What should I do next?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChkQY.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Responsive Images with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736363/responsive-images-with-css)

Answer (score 0):

make your images css "width:100%" instead of "max-width: 100%"

Comment: Tried, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

to make an image responsive, you must do this:

```
img {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
```

if you are using bootstrap:
for bootstrap 3: add *.img-responsive* to your image.
for bootstrap 4: add *.img-fluid* to your image.

hope it help :)

Comment: Tried, nothing changed.You code made my site look as in very first picture.
May be it is used in site, but I am not familiar with bootstrap.

Comment: https://vladmakeev.net/dieta-eto-legko-kak-derzhat-dietu-i-ne-sorvatsya

Problem in mobile and tablet version of posts. 

Featured Images are cropped.

Comment: set the width: 100%; in both image and it's parent div

Comment: and also remove the *left* margin.

Comment: Thank you! Image is good. But one change left: there is huge gap between newly sized image and text that is cannot be fixed through height: auto. What to do? (I attached one more image in question to show you)