# How to resize the image without stretching and distorting it

Tags: css, image, scale

I would like my images to look good on any device. On my homepage I'm using ContentViews plugin to list the latest articles posted. In the settings of the plugin I can set the thumbnail to be different sizes.

Currently I set it to medium (300x300), but when I looked at the site, the thumbnails were in different shapes. So I set a custom css:

> width: 300px; height: 270px;

Now the images have the same size, but some of them look bad. Is there a css code to somehow scale the images of any sizes, so they don't look stretched? So I don't have to manually edit them in PS, for example?

My site: http://slovosalanov.sk/test/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Responsive Images with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736363/responsive-images-with-css)

Comment: If you only give `width` or `height`, the other value is calculated in scale.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) property to display the image correctly regardless of the aspect ratio of the containing box or image. This way you can have uniform sized boxes with any image inside.

```
.pt-cv-wrapper img {
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Here is a [polyfill for IE and Edge.](https://github.com/bfred-it/object-fit-images/)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for I just couldn't find it on Google. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :)