# How to autofit image in parent container?

Tags: html, css

There is parent container with image inside:

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transform-origin: center;
    height: inherit;
    cursor: move;
}

.wrapper {
       width: 680px;
       height: 500px;
       overflow: hidden;
 }

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="parent">
      <img class="image" src="">
    </div>
</div>
```

When I load image with height more 500px I see overflow image. How to autofit and scale image in `.parent` block.

Comment: [Fit image perfectly in a dynamic-sized container](https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/DpmnK)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize the image without stretching and distorting it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49839734/how-to-resize-the-image-without-stretching-and-distorting-it)

Comment: `height:100%;width:100%;` on `.parent` You're limiting the height, The image you're adding is larger than the limit you provided, So make sure the parent of that image respects the height constrain you imposed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
.image {
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `width: 100%;` and `height:100%;` to the `.image` class. Also, `object-fit: cover;` will  clip the image to the container, maintaining its aspect ratio.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 680px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  height: inherit;
  cursor: move;
}

.image {
   width: 100%;
   height:100%;
   object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    <img class="image" src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1838/1*MI686k5sDQrISBM6L8pf5A.jpeg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This approach will also stretch the image if the aspect ratio of the container is different to the image.

Comment: @Coffeebean oh yes, OP has asked to autofit to the `.parent` . Dind't see that 1st time!

Comment: It does not work, I still get image with scrollbar not autofit in parent container size

Comment: @MeganClerc Can you put a link to your image, please?