# How do I make responsive images?

Tags: html, css

How do I make responsive images?
I will upload photos in different sizes!
It is necessary that the photos are stretched in length and width while maintaining their proportions.
When the page is reduced, the photos should also be reduced, but retain their proportions.
11:6 aspect ratio images.
I can't do it..
I also tried to do it on flexbox but it didn't work. 
Please show me how to do this. Can be on CSS grid or flexbox

```css
.row {
    margin: -10px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: minmax(auto, 100%);
}

.card {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    // width: 100%;
    // height: 100%;
}

.card-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 33%;
}

.image {
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.img1 {
    background-image: url(https://get.pxhere.com/photo/iphone-tree-nature-forest-grass-photography-fall-spring-green-phone-autumn-season-cellphone-photograph-image-habitat-21965.jpg);
}

.img2 {
    background-image: url(https://cs8.pikabu.ru/post_img/2016/06/08/9/og_og_146539895626849533.jpg);
}

.img3 {
    background-image: url(https://get.pxhere.com/photo/iphone-tree-nature-forest-grass-photography-fall-spring-green-phone-autumn-season-cellphone-photograph-image-habitat-21965.jpg);
}

.img4 {
    background-image: url(https://cs8.pikabu.ru/post_img/2016/06/08/9/og_og_146539895626849533.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-img">
            <img class="image img1" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="card-description">
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita, consequatur!
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-img">
            <img class="image img2" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="card-description">
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita, consequatur!
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-img">
            <img class="image img3" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="card-description">
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita, consequatur!
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-img">
            <img class="image img4" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="card-description">
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita, consequatur!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Responsive Images with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736363/responsive-images-with-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a complete solution!
This will keep the aspect ratio of the images and they are now adaptive.

You need to add the property (**position: relative;**) to the parent (**class="card-img"**).
And also add the bottom padding to the parent (**padding: 0% 0% 50% 0%;**), 50% is how much the image will be compressed from the bottom.
The image (**img**) needs to be positioned absolutely in relation to its parent (**class="card-img"**), (**position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;**)., Be sure to set the height and width (**height: 100%; width : 100%;**).
Also, in order for the image to stretch to the full width and height of the box, you need to set the (**object-fit: cover;**) property, this property is similar to "***background-size: cover;***".
Additionally, you can set the (**object-position: center;**) property to center the image, this property is similar to "***background-position: center;***".

```css
.row {
    margin: -10px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: minmax(auto, 100%);
}

.card {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.card-img {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0% 0% 58% 0%;
}

.card-img img {
    position: absolute;
    object-position: center;
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-img">
            <img class="img1" src="https://get.pxhere.com/photo/iphone-tree-nature-forest-grass-photography-fall-spring-green-phone-autumn-season-cellphone-photograph-image-habitat-21965.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="card-description">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sunt nam cumque fugiat, fuga enim, obcaecati, vel, similique numquam alias qui nisi cum? Porro quibusdam, labore! Porro voluptas quisquam, earum!
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-img">
            <img class="img2" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/7f/0e/52/7f0e525bd01b7ce821daa61da6d2a8b8.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="card-description">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sunt nam cumque fugiat, fuga enim, obcaecati, vel, similique numquam alias qui nisi cum? Porro quibusdam, labore! Porro voluptas quisquam, earum!
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-img">
            <img class="img3" src="https://cs8.pikabu.ru/post_img/2016/06/08/9/og_og_146539895626849533.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="card-description">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sunt nam cumque fugiat, fuga enim, obcaecati, vel, similique numquam alias qui nisi cum? Porro quibusdam, labore! Porro voluptas quisquam, earum!
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-img">
            <img class="img4" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/05/10/19/36/the-atlantic-ocean-3388522_1280.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="card-description">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sunt nam cumque fugiat, fuga enim, obcaecati, vel, similique numquam alias qui nisi cum? Porro quibusdam, labore! Porro voluptas quisquam, earum!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer -> Code only answers are considered low quality. And soemtimes they even are removed for that reason. It doesnt matter what you or I think. There are strict guidelines. One of them that answers should contain an explanation of the answer which your answer missing. Your answer might solve the issue. However the OP has no idea how your answer would solve the issue and therefor wont be able to reproduce it. As such it will be useless to the OP and deserves a down-vote aswell as an actual removal.

Answer (score 0):

If you can support [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit):

1. Remove the wrapping `.card-img` elements
2. Put the image url directly on the images: `<img src="...">`
3. On the `.image` elements set `height`, `width`, and `object-fit: contain;`

```css
.row {
  margin: -10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(auto, 100%);
}

.card {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 33%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="image" alt="" src="https://get.pxhere.com/photo/iphone-tree-nature-forest-grass-photography-fall-spring-green-phone-autumn-season-cellphone-photograph-image-habitat-21965.jpg">
    <div class="card-description">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita, consequatur!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="image" alt="" src="https://cs8.pikabu.ru/post_img/2016/06/08/9/og_og_146539895626849533.jpg">
    <div class="card-description">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita, consequatur!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="image" alt="" src="https://get.pxhere.com/photo/iphone-tree-nature-forest-grass-photography-fall-spring-green-phone-autumn-season-cellphone-photograph-image-habitat-21965.jpg">
    <div class="card-description">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita, consequatur!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="image" alt="" src="https://cs8.pikabu.ru/post_img/2016/06/08/9/og_og_146539895626849533.jpg">
    <div class="card-description">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita, consequatur!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! I already wrote the code. In your answer, the images are shrunk in width this is not what I needed. In my answer, the images are not squeezed in width! Please see for yourself. This happens when the screen width is 300px.